# Static business on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

When I do a search for a company on Google Maps, it's showing me the correct address/location with the orange bubble pin. Some business are static (white text). How does Google show this static business? I confirmed my business but it's not shown as static text.

[image: static vs searched business]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are place labels and appear based on the prominence of the listing. It isn't something that can be controlled since prominence is part of the ranking algorithm for local.

That said, part of the prominence factors for a given location include density. Maps only shows one place label per location, if at all. The most prominent listing is then displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your place to Google maps by using Google's [Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) tool. There is a step by step guide (with pictures) [here](http://www.iexposure.com/2011/06/16/how-to-get-a-google-places-label) that looks comprehensive.

Comment: I think this is the right way. But it is interesting, that Siwtzerland is not yet available. http://support.google.com/mapmaker/bin/static.py?hl=de&guide=30028&topic=1094318&page=guide.cs&answer=155415 But there are marked places in switzerland.

Comment: Previously google did try to guess using various listings, but I think it was a bit random as to what got labelled.